# feign client not receiving ResponseEntity

Tags: spring-cloud, openfeign

I am learning Feign (Spring 2.7.0 with cloud 2021.0.3) with my micro-services.  The communication between services is working but I am unable to have Feign actually receive a ResponseEntity - only the DTO or List.

I have a service endpoint that returns a list in a ResponseEntity:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class ApiController { 

  @GetMapping("/all")
  ResponseEntity getAll() {
        List<ApiKey> apiKeyList = apiService.getAll();
        if ( apiKeyList == null || apiKeyList.size() < 1) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .body(new ErrorResponse("No APIKeys were found "));
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(apiKeyList);
        }
```

The List contains multiple:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApiKey {

    @NotNull
    private String apiKey;
    private UUID uuid;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate beginDate;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate endDate;
```

The Feign client that actually makes the call is:

```
@FeignClient(name = "identity-service")
public interface IdentityServiceClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/all")
    public List<ApiKey> getAllApiKeys();
 // the above works, the below errors out:
    public ResponseEntity getAllApiKeys();
```

So the Feign client will work, as long as it expects List keyResponse
But I would like to have that in the ResponseEntity so that I can any potential status code.

How do I get feign client to work  with ResponseEntity?

Answer (score 0):

If jackson has issues with constructing the ResponseEntity because it has no no-args constructor try to use the ResponseEntityDecoder

```
Feign.builder()      
.decoder(new ResponseEntityDecoder(jacksonDecoder))
```

Comment: This answer is not clear.  At a guess, I tried this, but it didn't help:
`
    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {

        return new ResponseEntityDecoder(
                new JacksonDecoder());
    }`